# Ruby on rails polymorphic association on update deleting and insert, but it will update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I update model with nested attributes rails run query:

```
 DELETE FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."id" = ?  [["id", 14]]
 UPDATE "posts" SET ...
 INSERT INTO "assets" ("title", "assetable_id", "assetable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Poster Title"], ["assetable_id", 3], ["assetable_type", "Post"], ["created_at", "2016-07-27 07:01:38.054681"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-27 07:01:38.054681"]]
```

But I want update, not delete/insert. Yes, if remove `dependent: :destroy` from model it run update query, but I want destroy asset when post is destroy.

If I have stored more info in assert model, when update it will lost.

This is bug?

My models:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :poster, as: :assetable, class_name: 'Poster', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poster

end

class Poster < Asset

end
```

My controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to blogger_blog_posts_path(@blog)
    else
      @categories = Category.full_tree
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  ...

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :content, category_ids: [], :poster_attributes => [:title])
  end
end
```

rails version 4.2.5.1

Comment: Can you paste the `params` from your controller which results this?

Comment: Actually seeing your controller the issue seems to me of the nested form, just check when you are updating the `post` then are you getting the `id` of assets? If not rails treats it as a new `asset` as you can have only one `poster` it deletes the old one and adds a new one.

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"вњ“", "authenticity_token"=>"yZhNCObohxsYq/pU136cfmPv72l9RtoySC35nsW0h7h82UIyysnyWY8Kx1h84YbKLlTO155jPlkLVppJYDIL1Q==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Post Title", "description"=>"Post Description", "content"=>"<p>Post Content</p>", "category_ids"=>[""], "poster_attributes"=>{"title"=>"Poster Title", "id"=>"16"}}, "commit"=>"бѓЄбѓ•бѓљбѓ�бѓљбѓ”бѓ‘бѓ”бѓ‘бѓ�бѓЎ бѓЁбѓ”бѓњбѓђбѓ®бѓ•бѓђ", "blog_id"=>"2", "id"=>"3"}`

but rails says `Unpermitted parameter: id`

Comment: Permit the `id` in strong parameters, `:poster_attributes => [:title, :id]` and try if it works

Comment: yes, this will run update query, thanks :)
i will remove :id on create action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the strong parameters you have not permitted `id` for `poster_attributes` so just permit it and that should work:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :content, category_ids: [], :poster_attributes => [:title, :id])
end
```

As you have a `has_one` relationship so when you `update` the `post` it sends the title for the `poster` and as it doesn't contains the `id` attribute in it rails treats it as a new `poster` for the `post` and deletes the old one and creates a new one. So if you permit the `id` in the strong parameters as you are receiving it from the form it will update the existing `poster` only.

Comment: Yes it works, but is it safe? if user change in html
 `<input type="hidden" value="17" name="post[poster_attributes][id]" id="post_poster_attributes_id" />` value?

Comment: Hidden fields are never safe but for `nested_form` we only have this option so that the existing objects are updated. Or you may do it using some custom code.

Comment: If i change id value in html rails raise exception
`Couldn't find Poster with ID=18 for Post with ID=3`

I think it is safe